# can not access to items of a paginated union query results

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.3

I want to paginate a **Union** query result. I wrote this :

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

    $page = Input::get('page', 1);
    $paginate = 10;

    $members = DB::table("members")
                ->select("id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "created_at")
                ->where("site_id", $id);

    $users = DB::table("users")
                ->select("id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "created_at")
                ->where("site_id", $id)
                ->union($members)
                ->get()->toArray()

    $slice = array_slice($users, $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
    $data = new Paginator($slice, $paginate);

    return View::make('main.pages.search',compact('data','searchTerm'));
```

Now I want to access result in the `search` blade template.Suppose I wrote this :

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($data as $user)
        {{ $user->first_name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $data->links() }}
```

But I got this error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\wamp\www\aids\resources\views\main\pages\search.blade.php
```

That can not recognize `$user` and it's `name` property

What is Problem ?

**Update:**
while `return $data` from above coeds return this :

```
{
    "per_page": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "ali",
            "last_name": "hassani",
            "created_at": "2012-04-16 22:11:46",
            "email": "ali@gmail.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "first_name": "hossein",
            "last_name": "rezaei",
            "created_at": "2012-04-16 22:11:46",
            "email": "reza@gmail.com",
        },
    ]
}
```

I tried `$data->data` to access result but same error occures.

**Update 2:**

I found that when I added `{{dd($user)}}` like this :

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($data as $user)
        {{dd($user)}}
        {{ $user->first_name }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

that returns an `array` contain Result instead `object`.

Comment: you select first_name and last_name but you are trying to display `$user->name`?

Comment: I try that but same problem occures.

Comment: `var_dump($data)` and check if it hasn't added a new depth level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [@iCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7205649/icode) guidance I found that I should use [slice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-slice) instead `array_slice` method. in fact that part of code that used `array_slice` changed to :

```
$slice = $workshops->slice($paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you are calling function [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray) on the query result which converts the collection into a plain PHP `array`. If the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be converted to arrays.

So your `foreach` in view should be as:

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($data['data'] as $user)
        {{ $user['first_name'] }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I used `toArray` beacause first parameter of `array_slice` gives an Array only. for that I have to change collection eloquent to array. is there another way that prevents converting Eloquent models to array?

Comment: You can use [`slice`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-slice) method of collection which returns a slice of the collection starting at the given index.